# C++ Linux get CPU nominal frequency

Tags: c++, linux, cpu-speed

I need to get a CPU nominal frequency under Linux within C++ code. As far as I know, the `/proc/cpuinfo` contains a current frequency.

Is `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq`

always reliable as nominal frequency in kHz?

Or is there a better way to get this information from C++?

Comment: Just for your info, that file doesn't exist on my machine. The reason is possibly that the CPU doesn't support any dynamic frequency adjustment, so a maximum value is meaningless.

Comment: s/cpufrequ/cpufreq/g

Comment: I don't have the file that the OP mentions, either.

Comment: What are you ACTUALLY trying to achieve? The reason I ask is that it would probably give you a better answer if you tell us that, rather than ask about some particular file that may or may not exist now or in the future.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'd like to get a value of a CPU nominal (max) frequency.

Comment: For information, or are you going to use it for something?

Comment: It is the final goal. I have to pass it to a user as an information about system.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have any means to access this value, it doesn't even assume there is such a value. Even in your case, you are just looking at one of the CPUs, not all of them. This means that you will have to do something OS-dependent, which you can probably build in C++.

Anyhow, do you know of any tool providing that number? Get its sourcecode and see how it does it! Other than that, I'd look at /proc/cpuinfo and build the average of the "cpu MHz" values there. The `/proc` filesystem is basically a predecessor of the `/sys` filesystem, but the info should be the same.

Comment: I know, that this is OS-dependend and I have to get this value under Linux. Unfortunately /proc/cpuinfo contains a current frequency, not a maximum one.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a single universal way how to read the nominal frequency. You can read the nominal frequency of Intel processor from `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq` (nominal + 1 MHz) when using `acpi-cpufreq` scaling driver, however `intel_pstate` sets content of this file to maximum turbo frequency. Nevertheless there are alternative solutions. Intel CPUs have the nominal frequency written as a part of the CPU model name (readable using CPUID instruction when input EAX = 0x01 or from `/proc/cpuinfo`) or you may read the `MSR_PLATFORM_INFO (0xCE)` register.

EDIT: AMD processors provide the nominal frequency in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq` without additional 1 MHz

EDIT2: Some processors may have `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_nominal_freq` file, e.g. POWER9

Comment: afaik, that's feature of OS build, if it "knows" that CPU. Programs literally have to figure out the model and cross-reference it with datasheet. E.g. if processor is too new or too old or too exotic, all bets are off.

Comment: There are no bets, what I have written works perfectly for Intel processors. I am not so familiar with the AMD, but I am working with one right now, so I edited my answer to be more precise.